# How do I compare two tables with partial matches?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables with similar yet inexact data that contains both text and sometimes numbers.

I want to find a formula that helps me quickly recognize similar values and compare their sums.

(I cannot use VBA or anything other than just formulas)

Here is what I have so far: (this is a small example, my actual table is about 100+ rows)

[image: Example]

I have tried taking table 2 and breaking it down into separate cells.
I'm hoping to find a way to tell excel "search B3:B8 and if the text in the cell matches the three given variables in I4:K4 (for example) then give me the ID #/SUM of the corresponding match"

The result should be that excel can say for example that A Adam in table 2 is Adam A in table 1 and tell me his sum is 1200 or ID # is 100.

I unfortunately can't find my original attempt but I tried following these tutorials however with limited results.
When I am able to find matches I'm not sure how I can tell it to return the numbers next to the match.

[Tutorial 1](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3796-excel-check-if-cell-contains-one-of-several-values.html)

[Tutorial 2](https://www.careerprinciples.com/resources/index-match-with-multiple-criteria)

I'm not very experienced in Excel so any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Using Office 365 this does what you explained:

```
=LET(SORTCONCAT,LAMBDA(x,
          MAP(x,LAMBDA(y,
              TEXTJOIN(" ",,SORT(TEXTSPLIT(y,," ")))))),
XLOOKUP(SORTCONCAT(Table2[Name]),SORTCONCAT(Table1[Name]),Table1[ID '#],""))
```

This formula first creates a lambda function called `SORTCONCAT` which splits the cells of an input range per space delimiter, sort the splitted strings and rejoin them with space delimiter again.

If we apply `SORTCONCAT` to `Table1[Name]` and `Table2[Name]` we can use these inside `XLOOKUP` to search the matching values and it's matching ID (or change `Table1[ID '#]` into `Table1[sum]` to get the matching sum).

*Note this is designed to only work if the complete sorted strings match, if you need another type of match, you need to update your question with expected results and per case explanation why.*

[image]